# How to build partly typescript enabled project in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I had a normal react web app project. There was no `typescript` implementation.
So I added

> npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react
> @types/react-dom @types/jest

This command is to bring `typescript` into the project.
I have converted some components to `typescript` and some are still remaining as vanilla js components. Everything works in the local environment. Even though the build command is working without any issues. Once I deploy the build folder to the server It gives a completely blank page and no console errors as well.

This is my firebase hosted link https://portfolio-e251d.web.app/

This is my repo https://github.com/pathum-kalhan/react-material-ui-portfolio

Are there any special steps to build a partly typescript react project?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/allowJs.html

Comment: If you can build it locally, and it works, I would recommend checking out the build script run on the server. Might be some old command/something is cached.

Comment: which branch is deployed?